# lowercasing function doesn't work in a different function

Tags: python

Please bear with me, I am new to Python.

The first function I wrote was one to lowercase any uppercase characters in a string that passed through it, which works by itself, while ignoring any non-uppercase alphabetical ASCII characters.

However, when I try to use it in my second function, (which SHOULD use the lowercasing function on whatever the user inputs and then sticks it in a file) I'm left with a file that contains the the string that's initially passed through without any of the lowercasing function.

```
import os.path
from os import path


def lowercaser(text):
    text = [ord(c) for c in text]
    length = len(text)

    i = 0
    while length != i:
        if 65 <= text[i] <= 90:
            text[i] = text[i] + 32
        i += 1

    text = [chr(c) for c in text]
    text = "".join(text)


def does_rfid_list_exist():
    if path.exists("rfidList.txt"):
        print("File found!")

    else:
        print("File was not located! Creating new file.\n")
        f = open("rfidList.txt", "a+")
        user_input = input("Please enter your name!\n")
        lowercaser(user_input)
        f.write(user_input)
        f.close()


does_rfid_list_exist()
```

I have no idea why they don't work together, and I've broken it down as far as I can. Any ideas?

Comment: the code looks not out of the ordinary , the only issue that I see is even though you are calling the function you are not updating the `user_input` , return the `text` from the lower case function as well

`user_input = lowercaser(user_input)` , try using this

Comment: check out the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) on the Python docs. You may find a method of interest there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be expecting this call:

```
lowercaser(user_input)
```

to change the value of `user_input`.  It won't do this.  The reason is that string values are immutable, which means that every time you "change" a string, you create a new one.  The original string object is not touched.  So in this case, the variable `user_input` is pointing at a particular string when you call `lowercaser`.  Once that function returns, `user_input` will still be pointing at the same string.  Some other string will exist that will be the result of the processing the function did.

The way this usually works is that the `lowercaser` function will return the new string as the return value of the function, like this:

```
user_input = lowercaser(user_input)
```

This way, you are pointing `user_input` to a new string, the string that `lowercaser` produced for you.  But to get this to work, you have to fix your `lowercaser` function to return its result.  So you also have to add `return text` as the last line of your `lowercaser` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first learn how to define a function.
You can learn it in w3school or any other source or book.

I am posting the solution here but it won't be productive for you.

Put

```
return text
```

in the last line of function. And put

```
user_input=lowercaser(user_input)
```

instead of

```
lowercaser(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

the code looks not out of the ordinary , The only issue that I see is even though you are calling the function you are not updating the user_input

`user_input = lowercaser(user_input)`

Apart from this , return text from lower case function `return text`

```
import os.path
from os import path


def lowercaser(text):
    text = [ord(c) for c in text]
    length = len(text)

    i = 0
    while length != i:
        if 65 <= text[i] <= 90:
            text[i] = text[i] + 32
        i += 1

    text = [chr(c) for c in text]
    text = "".join(text)
    return text #### Change - 1


def does_rfid_list_exist():
    if path.exists("rfidList.txt"):
        print("File found!")

    else:
        print("File was not located! Creating new file.\n")
        f = open("rfidList.txt", "a+")
        user_input = input("Please enter your name!\n")
        user_input = lowercaser(user_input) #### Change - 2
        f.write(user_input)
        f.close()


does_rfid_list_exist()
```

Using `lower()` on `user_input`

```
import os.path
from os import path


def lowercaser(text):
    text = [ord(c) for c in text]
    length = len(text)

    i = 0
    while length != i:
        if 65 <= text[i] <= 90:
            text[i] = text[i] + 32
        i += 1

    text = [chr(c) for c in text]
    text = "".join(text)
    return text #### Change - 1


def does_rfid_list_exist():
    if path.exists("rfidList.txt"):
        print("File found!")

    else:
        print("File was not located! Creating new file.\n")
        f = open("rfidList.txt", "a+")
        user_input = input("Please enter your name!\n")
        user_input = user_input.lower() ### Change - 2
        f.write(user_input)
        f.close()


does_rfid_list_exist()
```

Comment: you can also use the `lower()` function natively as well on `user_input`

Answer (score 0):

Bruv, there is not return statement, and even if there was the variable isn't stored anywhere. Meaning that text (a local variable that can only be accessed inside the function it originates from), is not accessible, passed on or stored in function does_rfid_list_exist(). Another problem is that user_input, which seems to be the data you are trying to manipulate, does not change after lowercaser() function because nothing is returned and the data isn't stored in anything. What I would do to fix is

To make it so that user_input

return text
after
text = "".join(text)
and replace
lowercaser(user_input)
with
user_input = lowercaser(user_input)

I think you got confused and thought that user_input is a public class of some sort.